# Inserting CoreData Values into a UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to take data I've stored with CoreData, and create table cells displaying the stored information. Each cell should have data from two different attributes. After searching for a while, I haven't gotten any farther, and am not sure how to approach it. Thanks for your help!

Code used to store data:

```
        if state == 0 {
        var date = NSDate()
        toggleButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        state = 1


        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Times", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

        let startTimeVar = Times(entity: entityDescription!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        startTimeVar.startTime = date

        var error: NSError?

        managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            debug.text = err.localizedFailureReason
        } else {
            debug.text = "Started at \(date)"
        }
    } else {
        toggleButton.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        state = 0
        var date = NSDate()
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Times", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

        let endTimeVar = Times(entity: entityDescription!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        endTimeVar.endTime = date

        var error: NSError?

        managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            debug.text = err.localizedFailureReason
        } else {
            debug.text = "Stopped at \(date)"
        }


    }
```

Picture of CoreData setup:

[image: Picture of CoreData setup]

Comment: Explain what the code you're showing does wrong

Comment: @Wain The code doesn't do anything wrong as far as I can tell. The code is showing how I store the data with CoreData, I am asking how to retrieve the data, and create table cells to display each one. Does that help?

Comment: It helps in that your question is too broad and you need to google search for a tutorial...

Comment: @Wain if you could point any out that would be helpful, I have yet to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has a [good Core Data tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift).

To answer your question, there are a few classes in involved with querying data:

- [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html)
- [NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html)
- [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/index.html) (optional)
- [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html) (optional)

Here's how you'd actually fetch the data.

```
// Create a fetch request for the desired entity
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Times")

// Optionally add a predicate to filter the results
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate("startTime > %@", someDateObject)

// Optionally add an array of sort descriptors to sort the results
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: true)
]

// Execute the request
var error: NSError?
let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Time]

// Handle the error
if let error = error {
    failure(error)
}
```